# style tag content can be truncated in Microsoft Edge

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

Given the following HTML document displayed in Microsoft Edge (110.0.1587.57), and the content of a style tag exceeds 10,000 characters, Edge will act as though classes in the style tag found after the 10k character mark do not exist.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>.test{background-color:orange}p{color:green}</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>This text should be green!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you change the code above and duplicate the ".test{background-color:orange}" approximately 350 times, you will have a style tag long enough to recreate the problem. The p style should remain at the end or at least beyond the 10,000 character mark.

When you open the developer tools by clicking on the paragraph tag and inspecting the html, the css section does not show the style for the p tag. And consequently, the text is black.

On the test html, there are some times when the text comes up green. This is not the case in the actual problem environment so I have not perfectly recreated the problem. However, the test html does demonstrate the problem if I let it set for a while. The text will turn black again and the css section will no longer show the p style being applied.

When I run the same test in Firefox, the p style displays correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried testing the issue with the **Microsoft Edge (110.0.1587.57)** and **Google Chrome**.

In both browsers, text shown in the green color.

[image]

When we check the CSS code under Style tag using the Dev tools, it shows ellipsis because the length of the CSS is long.

[image]

But it does not mean that CSS that not displayed here, not got executed.

When you click the element on the page, you could see the CSS applied to it.

[image]

Beside the CSS, there is a link to source code. If you click it, you will see the whole code.

[image]

I have tried several times, I did not see the black text or the CSS is not applied to text even after pasting the `.test{background-color:orange}` more then 350 times.

If you still seeing the issue, I would suggest try to update the Edge to 111.x version and see the results.